# Using Filestream for a filepath that isn't "local"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, filestream

So I have a filepath for an image `\DataEntry\Image\RenderOriginalImage\3237319@Research` that I need to load from a controller in my MVC app. When I tried just passing it into filestream normally it returned an exception

```
Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\DataEntry\Image\RenderOriginalImage\3237319@Research'
```

which makes sense because the path of this image file isn't local it's on the website files... Any ideas how I can access this filepath?

Answer (score 1):

If the file isn't located on the server running the code, you can't use `FileStream` (unless you can access it through an UNC path--which you haven't detailed)...  If it's somewhere else you'll have to use a different type of `Stream` type to access the data.  If you provide more detail about that, someone can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Ok so I think the file path data I have is more similar to a UNC path than anything else. I didn't know that filepath only worked with files on the computer. How would I create a stream from a UNC path?

Comment: actually no the path i have is a relative path... How would I go about loading a relative path?

Comment: Huh?  You can't have a relative path *and* "isn't local".  Please be more clear.